# RxJS combineLatest: how to get emit after just one value changes?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm trying to learn the RxJS library. One of the cases I don't quite understand is described in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akauppi/eb9rsk00/) (code also below).

```
var A= new Rx.Subject();
var B= new Rx.Subject();

A.onNext(0);    

// '.combineLatest' needs all the dependency Observables to get emitted, before its combined signal is emitted.
//
// How to have a combined signal emitted when any of the dependencies change (using earlier given values for the rest)?
//    
A.combineLatest( B, function (a,b) { return a+b; } )
 .subscribe( function (v) { console.log( "AB: "+ v ); } );

B.onNext("a");  
A.onNext(1);
```

I'd like to get two emits to the "AB" logging. One from changing B to "a" (A already has the value 0). Another from changing A to 1.

However, only changes that occur after a subscribe seem to matter (even though A has a value and thus the combined result could be computed).

Should I use "hot observables" for this, or some other method than `.combineLatest`?

My problem in the actual code (bigger than this sample) is that I need to make separate initialisations after the subscribes, which cuts stuff in two separate places instead of having the initial values clearly up front.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how the `Subjects` work. `Subjects` *are* hot Observables. They do not hold on to values, so if they receive an `onNext` with no subscribers than that value will be lost to the world.

What you are looking for is a either the `BehaviorSubject` or the `ReplaySubject` both of which hold onto past values that re-emit them to new subscribers. In the former case you always construct it with an initial value

```
//All subscribers will receive 0
var subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);

//All subscribers will receive 1
//Including all future subscribers
subject.onNext(1);
```

in the latter you set the number of values to be replayed for each subscription

```
var subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
//All new subscribers will receive 0 until the subject receives its 
//next onNext call
subject.onNext(0);
```

Rewriting your example it could be:

```
var A= new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);
var B= new Rx.Subject();    

// '.combineLatest' needs all the dependency Observables to get emitted, before its combined signal is emitted.
//
// How to have a combined signal emitted when any of the dependencies change (using earlier given values for the rest)?
//    
A.combineLatest( B, function (a,b) { return a+b; } )
 .subscribe( function (v) { console.log( "AB: "+ v ); } );

B.onNext("a");  
A.onNext(1);

//AB: 0a
//AB: 1a
```

On another note, realizing of course that this is all new to you, in most cases you should not need to use a `Subject` directly as it generally means that you are trying to wrangle Rx into the safety of your known paradigms. You should ask yourself, where is your data coming from? How is it being created? If you ask those questions enough, following your chain of events back up to the source, 9 out of 10 times you will find that there is probably an `Observable` wrapper for it.

Comment: @akauppi yep mouse drags are of course observable events, check out [fromEvent](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md). In the fullness of time when you've more Rx experience, you can learn how to string this all together from the source of observable mouse events all the way to your final observable result using only Rx operators without ever needing to work directly with `Subjects`.